# Design tab is not rendering MaterialcardView in Material3 theme

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

First I was unable to find why the android studio design tab is not rendering views especially `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` After some time I figured out that if i replace `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` with `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar` in `themes.xml` then design tabs shows empty.

[image]

Here's my MaterialCardView

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card_climate_change"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:strokeWidth="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">
...
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

The above code works well in Material2 but creates problems in Material3.

Comment: I have the same bug, you were able to solve it without going back to Material 2.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. The issue resolved itself once I updated to the latest version of Android Studio (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2).